# R - ggplot2 plotting lognormal curve on histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So i have a set of data which follows the lognormal distribution, i have found the values for mu and sigma and am now trying to plot a histogram of the data alongside the PDF of the lognormal. However plotting the line seems to put it below 0 which doesnt seem to make sense, what am i doing wrong here, it seems like the line should be 5 y values higher.

Thanks
M

```
h <- read.table("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names="id")
library("ggplot2")
d <- ggplot(data=h, aes(h$time)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.8) + 
stat_function(fun = dlnorm, args = list(meanlog = 2.2, sdlog = 0.44, log = TRUE), colour = "red")
d
```

Graph Produced
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want `log = TRUE`? This is taking the `log(probabilities)` which since they are < 1 are coming up negative. Also this won't be right either since `dlnorm` will give you `density`. Your current plot shows counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make the comparision:

```
h <- data.frame(time = rlnorm(100, 2.2, .44))
library("ggplot2")
d <- ggplot(data=h) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.8, aes(x = time, ..density..)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dlnorm, args = list(meanlog = 2.2, sdlog = 0.44), 
                colour = "red")
d
```

As suggested, turn `log = TRUE` off and then use `..density..` to get a frequency instead of a count.

Comment: Thank you very much, very silly of me to not realise the y axis was going up way past 1